# DRF+Ajax Method "POST" not allowed. viewsets + router

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I am getting error 'Method "POST" not allowed' while running the api. I have use ModelViewSet and Routers
Also use Ajax on front-end to send "POST"-request.
I did GET and PUT, and it's work perfectly, but POST - never.
in app.views.py

```
class PostsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = Posts.objects.filter(is_published=True).select_related()
serializer_class = PostDetailSerializer
# permission_classes = (IsAuthor, MyPermission)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(author=self.request.user)
```

in app.serializers.py

```
class PostDetailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
# author = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='author.username')
author = UserInfoSerializer(read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Posts
    fields = ('url', 'id', 'title', 'text', 'created', 'author', 'last_modified', 'is_published')
```

in permissions.py

```
class IsAuthor(permissions.BasePermission):
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    print(request.method)
    if (request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS or request.user and
        request.user.is_authenticated()):
        return True
    return obj.author == request.user
```

class MyPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

```
allowed_methods = ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS']

def has_permission(self, request, view):
    return request.method in self.allowed_methods
```

in urls.py

```
class PostsRouter(routers.SimpleRouter):
routes = [
    routers.Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
        mapping={'get': 'list'},
        name='{basename}-list',
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'},
        detail=False
    ),
    routers.Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
        mapping={'get': 'retrieve'},
        name='{basename}-detail',
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'},
        detail=True
    ),
    routers.Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}/create/$',
        mapping={'post': 'create'},
        name='{basename}-create',
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'},
        detail=True
    ),
    routers.Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/update/$',
        mapping={'put': 'update'},
        name='{basename}-update',
        initkwargs={'suffix': 'Detail'},
        detail=True
    ),

]
router = PostsRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'', views.PostsViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Please help!!!
PS:
Full code is on github https://github.com/NikolayPogoreliy/SimpleBlog

Comment: Did you pass the csrf token in your headers? Also did you setup cors? If not here is a useful tool https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers

Comment: Yes. CSRF  - headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken"),} CORS is installed

Comment: what url are using to post?

Comment: "/blog/create/" named as 'posts-create'